# How to get terminal's Character Encoding

Tags: linux

Now I change my gnome-terminal's character encoding to "GBK" (default it is UTF-8), but how can I get the value(character encoding) in my Linux?

Comment: Short writeup: [Unix Terminals: Surviving the Encoding Hell](http://benjamin-schweizer.de/unix-terminals-surviving-the-encoding-hell.html)

Answer (score 120):

The terminal uses [environment variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) to determine which [character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Character_sets.2C_maps_and_code_pages) to use, therefore you can determine it by looking at those variables:

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

or

```
echo $LANG
```

Comment: These environment variables are used by applications that are using the terminal for I/O.  The terminal emulator itself has no knowledge of them whatsoever, and its currently effective character encoding is a setting somewhere within the emulator program (a data member inside a libvte class in the case of GNOME Terminal).

Comment: the ordering of variables suggested here is not good.  a more complete solution would be something like: echo ${LC_ALL:-${LC_CTYPE:-${LANG}}}.  then again, the variable being set isn't a guarantee that they're valid, so you should stick to the `locale` program (as seen in other answers here).

Comment: As @JdeBP said, the terminal does *not* use the `locale` environment variables to determine its encoding. The terminal can however let applications that interact it know its encoding by setting the `locale` environment variables. For instance, on macOS you can choose the terminal encoding and optionally set the `locale` environment variables at terminal startup in `Terminal` > `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Advanced`.

Answer (score 112):

`locale` command with no arguments will print the values of all of the relevant environment variables except for LANGUAGE.

For current encoding:

```
locale charmap
```

For available locales:

```
locale -a
```

For available encodings:

```
locale -m
```

Comment: This is what worked for me on a CentOS system. It showed the system encoding based upon current language settings. The terminal settings used to get to that machine are a different story and a function of the client being used.

Answer (score 49):

Check encoding and language:

```
$ echo $LC_CTYPE
ISO-8859-1
$ echo $LANG
pt_BR
```

Get all languages:

```
$ locale -a
```

Change to pt_PT.utf8:

```
$ export LC_ALL=pt_PT.utf8 
$ export LANG="$LC_ALL"
```

Answer (score 20):

If you have Python:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"
```

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, no.

Circumstantial indications from `$LC_CTYPE`, `locale` and such might seem alluring, but these are completely separated from the encoding the terminal application (actually an emulator) happens to be using when displaying characters on the screen.

They only way to detect encoding for sure is to output something only present in the encoding, e.g. `ä`, take a screenshot, analyze that image and check if the output character is correct.

So no, it's not possible, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

To see the current locale information use `locale` command. Below is an example on RHEL 7.8

```
[usr@host ~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

Examination of https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html, the xterm control character documentation, shows that it follows the ISO 2022 standard for character set switching.  In particular ESC % G selects UTF-8.
So to force the terminal to use UTF-8, this command would need to be sent.  I find no way of querying which character set is currently in use, but there are ways of discovering if the terminal supports national replacement character sets.

However, from [charsets(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/charsets.7.html), it doesn't look like GBK (or GB2312) is an encoding supported by ISO 2022 and xterm doesn't support it natively.  So your best bet might be to use iconv to convert to UTF-8.

Further [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code) shows that a (significant) subset of GBK is EUC, which is a ISO2022 code, so ISO2022 capable terminals may be able to display GBK natively after all, but I can't find any mention of activating this programmatically, so the terminal's user interface would be the only recourse.