# wget -- unknown characters

Tags: linux, wget

```
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz
--2013-12-01 17:04:31--  http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz
Length: 16341773 (16M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ***â€œgettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gzâ€***
```

When I use wget to download the gettext source, some unknown characters appear.

Comment: Are the ***s really there, or did you just add them for emphasis?

Comment: I just add them for emphasis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just an encoding issue with your terminal environment. If you use `ls` you will see your file has been saved with the correct filename.

wget is trying to use "smart quotes", but is using the wrong encoding for some reason. See [How to get terminal's Character Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/how-to-get-terminals-character-encoding) (which is probably not the best reference for a newbie - ask in a comment if you don't understand it!)

Comment: Many thanks.
I know the reason now.
Originally, I use the Xshell to connect to the host machine. And the encoding in my Xshell is default, which will cause this problem. I change the encoding to "UTF-8", and it works now.
Thanks again