# Printing filled and empty squares within Linux console produce garbage characters

Tags: c++, linux, string, character-encoding

I'm trying to solve the programming challenge defined [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56e6705b715e72fef0000647/train/cpp).
Basically, I have solved the essence of the question with normal characters, for instance the execution of `zoom(7)` returns

```
0000000
0xxxxx0
0x000x0
0x0x0x0
0x000x0
0xxxxx0
0000000
```

which is the correct pattern.

However, as additional difficulty the characters must be an empty square `□` at the place of `0` and a filled one `■` at the place of `x`.

If I try to replace those characters I get as result

```
□□□□□□□��□□□□
�■■■■■□□□□□��□□□□
��□□□��■■■□□□□□��□□□□
���■�□□��■■■□□□□□��□□□□
��□□□��■■■□□□□□��□□□□
�■■■■■□□□□□��□□□□
□□□□□□□��□□□□
```

I have no idea what causes the problem, if the console cannot print such squares, or if I need some additional specifications when printing the floats, or whatever. I tried defining the squared as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438222/print-a-filled-square-in-console), but nothing changed at all.

Here's a basic sample returning the 3x3 solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string res;

    std::string prim;
    std::string sec;

        //~ prim = "x";         // filled square
        //~ sec = "0";          // empty square

        prim = "■";         // filled square
        sec = "□";          // empty square

    res += sec; res += sec; res += sec; res += "\n";
    res += sec; res += prim; res += sec; res += "\n";
    res += sec; res += sec; res += sec; res += "\n";

    std::cout << res;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: My guess would be you need to use `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`, and format the Unicode strings for the characters in a proper C++ format.  Not too familiar with that myself, though.