# How to set proper chracter encoding for GNU/Linux

Tags: java, linux, string, db2, wcs

I am creating text file in Linux server system, to upload the data to some other system. I am reading the data from DB2 database.
If create the file in my development environment that is windows then there no problem all the character are coming properly.

For example If i print this line in windows`System.out.println(productx.getDescription().getName());` 
output will be `511™ Slim Fit - Rinsed Playa Jeans`

The same line if it's executed on Linux system it is producing the below output

```
 511? Slim Fit - Rinsed Playa Jeans
```

If I execute the below code in that Linux  system `Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
System.out.println("Default encoding: " + charset + " (Aliases: "+ charset.aliases() + ")");` The output is

```
Default encoding: ISO-8859-1 (Aliases: [819, ISO_8859-1, csISOLatin1, l1, IBM-819, 8859-1, IBM819, ISO8859-1, latin1, ISO_8859_1, ISO-8859-1:1987, cp819, iso-ir-100, 8859_1, ISO8859_1])
```

How to fix this problem ? Can some body help me. I tried at lot of solutions but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default charset is Latin-1 (aka. ISO 8859-1). This charset does not seem to contain the character `™`. Chances are your JVM runs with this default because your system is configured to use Latin-1. You make sure that both your system and your JVM use UTF-8.

See [How to get terminal's Character Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/)

Comment: The problem is I can not change character encoding of the server, Can I write the data to File in binary format and FTP to a other system where there character can be read

Comment: I am able to create file with different encoding. Thanks