# How to setup a physical, hardware terminal on Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, hardware, tty

I was wondering if

a) it's possible to use a real hardware terminal/console/teletype with Ubuntu/Debian instead of an emulated one

b) Where can I find the specifications for the way data are transmitted (ie character encoding, linebreaks, checksums/error correction(if applicable) )

c) with what kind of interface I can use to connect the hardware (if there are limitations)

I know it's probably an obscure question, but I aren't almost all linux distros are supposed to be still backwards compatable with physical terminals?

Answer (score 0):

a)Yes, there is a hardware Terminal in Ubuntu / Debian.

It's called TTY in short ... (TeleTYpe/TeleTYpewrite)

There are different levels of TTY where user Programs / GUI and other Kernel functions are executed.

In case of Ubuntu, tty7 is usually used by Xorg, do provide your graphical environment (to be more exact, it provides a "windowing system" only, and things like the gnome - as a desktop environment solution - runs "top of it").

to switch to a hardware terminal use the following key combinations in Ubuntu/ Debian:
ALT +CTRL +F1

to switch back to the GUI use ALT+ CTRL+ F7

You can have multiple Hardware Terminals -- 
   using the combinations: ALT+CTRL+ (F1-F6)

b) for the answer to this question you may refer:
    [How to get terminal's Character Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/how-to-get-terminals-character-encoding)

c)Yes there are limitations.... You will be limited to use a keyboard.

There are 3 standard I/O available for the tty terminal.
  &0 -  standard input (keyboard)
  &1 -  standard output (display / Monitor)
  &2 -  standard Error (File /standard Output)

Usage $  bash script.sh > &2