# PHP: corrupting of cyrillic characters in terminal in some case with fgets function

Tags: php, terminal, console

So, I tried to input cyrillic symbols to save them. I use `fgets()` function to get symbols (actually symfony console uses it). The problem is I can't prevent random corrupting of symbols when I get them. To simplify, I made the next code:

```
$i=0;
while ($i !== 100) {
    $i++;
    $str = fgets(STDIN, 4096);
    echo $str;
}
die;
```

I entered `ТАйтл`, `Некоторый текст`, `Тайтл`. Always on a first or second entering I got this wrong symbols. Example of wrong symbols:
`ðóððÉð╣Ðéð╗` (`ТАйтл`).

I tried to play with `mb_convert_encoding`, but generally, I always have UTF-8 encoding, so it's not about converting. But about in this case?

Many thanks for helping.

Comment: the problem is in your terminal encoding. can you do what's will be written in terminal - echo $LANG

Comment: It's empty. Linux version just in case: `Linux version 4.9.125-linuxkit (root@659b6d51c354) (gcc version 6.4.0 (Alpine 6.4.0) ) #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018`

Comment: try this to check your terminal charset - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/how-to-get-terminals-character-encoding

Comment: and this is ther help - https://benjamin-schweizer.de/unix-terminals-surviving-the-encoding-hell.html :) good luck!